# The Firestore's subcollection return empty with no errors

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to make an application where I could retrieve the specific user's subcollection data.

Specifically my goal is to retrieve all of the plants contains in the plants collection.

Like that:
[image]

Here is the code on how I tried to retried the subcollection.

```
@Singleton
class PlantRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val userRef: CollectionReference
): PlantRepository {
    override fun getPlantsFromFirestore() = callbackFlow {

    
       val user = Firebase.auth.currentUser!!.uid
       // Log.d("Data:","${user}")
        val snapshotListener = userRef.document(user).collection("plants").orderBy("name").addSnapshotListener{ snapshot, e ->

            val response = if (snapshot != null) {
                val plant = snapshot.toObjects(Plant::class.java)

                Success(plant)
            } else {
                Error(e?.message ?: e.toString())
            }
            trySend(response).isSuccess
        }
        awaitClose {
            snapshotListener.remove()
        }
    }
```

Perhaps there could be the issue with the AppModule file itself, since I'm not experienced with the Hilt library.

Here is the code of the AppModule:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideFirebaseFirestore()= Firebase.firestore

    @Provides
    fun provideUserRef(
       db: FirebaseFirestore

   )=db.collection("users")

   @Provides
    fun provideUserRepository(
       userRef: CollectionReference
 ): PlantRepository = PlantRepositoryImpl(userRef)

    @Provides
    fun provideUseCases(
        repo: PlantRepository
    ) = UseCases(
        getPlants = GetPlants(repo),
        addPlant = AddPlant(repo),
        deletePlant = DeletePlant(repo),
        editPlant= EditPlant(repo)

    )


}
```

Here are the content of the Plant class.

```
data class Plant(
    val id:String?=null,
    val plant_category_id:String?=null,
    val image:String?=null,
    val name:String?=null,
    val category:String?=null,
    val room_location:String?=null,
)
```

Main activity class:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            IndoorPlantCareTheme {
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                SetupNavGraph(navController = navController)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the the IndoorPlantCare.kt:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class IndoorPlantCare: Application()
```

Here is the Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.indoorplantcare">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:name=".IndoorPlantCare"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.IndoorPlantCare"
        tools:targetApi="31"
        tools:ignore="MissingClass">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.IndoorPlantCare">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

UI:

```
  when (plantResponse) {
            is Loading -> ProgressBar()
            is Success ->LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(Color.White)
            ) {
              
                items(items = plantResponse.data) {
                    CardList(model = it) { model ->
                        Log.d("TAG", "Clicked on $model")
                       // navController.navigate(route = NavScreens.DetailScreen.name + "/$model")

                    }


                }
            }
            is Error -> printError(plantResponse.message)
        }
    }
}
@Composable
fun CardList(model: Plant, onItemClick:(String) -> Unit = {} ){

    Card(
        shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(
                bottom = 6.dp,
                top = 6.dp,
                start = 6.dp,
                end = 6.dp,
            )
            .clickable {
                onItemClick(model.id.toString())

            }
            .fillMaxWidth(),

        elevation = 8.dp

    ) {
        Column {
            Image(
                painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(model = model.image) ,
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(125.dp),
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
            )

            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(
                        top = 12.dp,
                        bottom = 12.dp,
                        start = 8.dp,
                        end = 8.dp
                    )
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = model.name.toString(),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth(0.85f)
                        .wrapContentWidth(Alignment.Start),
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5
                )
            }
            Text(
                text = "Author : ${model.room_location}",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth(0.85f)
                    .wrapContentWidth(Alignment.Start)
                    .padding(
                        top = 12.dp,
                        bottom = 12.dp,
                        start = 8.dp,
                        end = 8.dp
                    ),


                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6
            )

        }
    }

}
```

I have tried tinkering it, but unfortunately I started getting the Hilt related errors that I'm unsure on how to fix them.

Other that, I receive no error or even do not receive any debug messages when I tried to debug it in the `Log.d("Data:","${user}")` line.

In that case, it could be the issue with AppModule itself. I would appreciate if I could receive the guidance.

Comment: Your code looks good to me at the first glance. This is what I have also done it.
You say *I started getting the Hilt related errors*. What are those errors? Besides that,
please edit your question and add the content of your `Plant` class. Please also edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo I appreciate your reply. I have added the content of the `Plant` class and also I added the picture of how my Firestore looks.  Regarding Hilt related error I got `[Dagger/MissingBinding]` error it when I tried  editing the AppModule in hope that the bug will be fixed.

Comment: Show us also your activity class, your app class that extends Application, and your manifest file. Did follow this [explanation](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8) with the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreCleanArchitectureApp)?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes, I did follow the article very close. The only thing that could have been different is that I have added additionally Authentication with email and password, and also how I present the values that I want to retrieve. I  also posted the UI side just in case. I also added more snippets to of the code you asked to. As always I appreciate your help.

Comment: Perhaps, that error comes from the part where you're using authentication. Your actual code looks good to me.

Comment: @AlexMamo  Alright,  I will try  to do  more testing  with  the authentication code.

Comment: Have you tried testing with the authentication code?

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni Yes, I have found the problem and managed to solve it

Comment: If you find the solution, then post it as an answer. So it might be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone ends up here with no idea what to try...
I had the same problem and in my case it got resolved when I added a field inside the document that only had a subcollection.
[Place to add the field in an arquitecture like the one shown in the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmHIx.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).